# gtsummary - present proportion of unknown/missing values separately

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have a categorical variable (ethnicity) with unknown values, and I am trying to present it with gtsummary so that the proportions are computed separately for known and unknown values

I have managed to get to [this stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUj65.png)

But I cannot find a way to calculate the proportion of missing values separately

My code is something along these lines

```
trial %>%      
  select(age, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    missing = "if_any",
     statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                               response~ c("{n} ({p}%)",
                                        "{N_miss} ({p_miss})"),
                               all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
  )
```

I did try the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65414864/how-to-add-percentage-to-unknown-in-gtsummary/65415121#comment115656841_65415121) (i.e. `fct_replace_na` and setting `missing = "no"`) but it keeps including the unknown rows in the overall proportions

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question, and I think I should implement something to make this easier. Anyway, here's how I would go about this: 1. Define a new variable indicating if the variable is missing. 2. Summarize this variable in the table and update the default label to Unknown, 3. Indent the missing rows.

Example Below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.0'


tbl <-
  trial %>%      
  mutate(across(c(age, response), is.na, .names = "{.col}_missing")) %>%
  select(age, age_missing, response, response_missing, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    missing = "no",
    label = ends_with("_missing") ~ "Unknown",
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     response~ c("{n} ({p}%)",
                                 "{N_miss} ({p_miss})"),
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
  ) %>%
  modify_column_indent(columns = label, rows = endsWith(variable, "_missing"))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>