# How do i group variables or put more variables under same header in my summarytable?

Tags: r, gtsummary

as a beginner in both R and gtsummary i've encountered a problem when making my tbl_summary. The data in pre-FEV1, pre-FVC, post-FEV1 and post-FVC isn't behaving as i'd like. The missing values of pre-FEV1 and pre-FVC aswell as post-FEV1 and post-FVC are the same and therefore i'd like to only have 1 missing row per pair. What would be even greater is having the 2 pairs "grouped" as follows:

| Pre-bronchodilator spirometry |

|   FEV1   |  {mean} ({sd}) | ...

|   FVC    |  {mean} ({sd}) | ...

| Post-bronchodilator spirometry |

|   FEV1   |  {mean} ({sd}) | ...

|   FVC    |  {mean} ({sd}) | ...

This is my current code for the table below

```
Tib1 <- Data %>%
+   select(c(sex, alder_basis, etnisknavn, udd1, udd2, lsprefev, lsprefvc, lspostfev, lspostfvc, av)) %>%
+   unlabelled() %>%
+   tibble()
> Tib1$lspostfvc <- as.double(Tib1$lspostfvc)
> Tib1$av <- fct_na_value_to_level(Tib1$av,level = "NA")
> Tib1
> Tbl1 <- tbl_summary(Tib1, 
+             by = av,
+             value = list(sex ~ "Female", etnisknavn ~ "No Danish descent"),
+             label = list(sex ~ "Female", etnisknavn ~ "Non-Danish descent", alder_basis ~ "Age (as of January 1st 2004)", lspostfvc ~ "Post FVC"),
+             statistic = list(
+               all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
+               all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
+             digits = c(alder_basis) ~ 1, 
+             missing_text = "(Missing, n)"
+             ) %>%
+   add_p() %>%
+   add_overall() %>%
+   modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1":"stat_8") ~ "**Age of AC debut**") %>%
+   modify_caption("**Table 1. Patient Characteristics**") %>%
+   modify_footnote(
+     update = all_stat_cols() ~ 
+       "mean (SD) for continous; n (%) for categorical"
+   )
> 
> Tbl1
```

[My current summary table showing pre-FEV1, pre-FVC, post-FEV1 and post-FVC as individual variables and each with corresponding missing values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m236n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fairly good workaround thanks to this:
[gtsummary - present proportion of unknown/missing values separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72030309/gtsummary-present-proportion-of-unknown-missing-values-separately)

I first split my Tib1 dataframe into 3 smaller tibbles (one with the general characteristics, one with pre-bronchodilator spirometry data and one with post-bronchodilator spirometry) and then using the mutate and is.na functions as desribed in the above post to search for NAs and counting these in a separate row. Then creating a tbl_summary for each tibble and lastly stacking them with tbl_stack.

I'll leave this question here instead of deleting to help others if a similar obstacles shows